# Compare two datatables and delete duplicates (without join)

Tags: c#, linq, duplicates

I need to compare two datatables, to delete the duplicates and then to fill a gridview.

This is what I have try so far

```
DataTable cols = new DataTable();
DataTable cols2 = new DataTable();
DataTable cols3 = cols.Copy();

foreach(DataRow row1 in cols2.Rows) 
{
 bool isRecordExist = false;
 foreach(DataRow row2 in cols.Rows) 
 {
  if (row1 == row2) 
  {
   isRecordExist = true;
  }

  if (!isRecordExist) 
  {
   cols3.ImportRow(row1);
  }
 }
}

dgvfcolumns.DataSource = cols3;
```

but instead of removing the duplicate it just adds the rows from 2nd datatable (cols2) to the the 1st(cols).

any idea?
I also like to ask if I have to convert my datatables to arrays?
thank you

**Edit**
I fill My first datatable with combinations like this...
 [Obtaining combinations of k elements from n in C#](https://www.technical-recipes.com/2017/obtaining-combinations-of-k-elements-from-n-in-c/#comment-52343)

The second datatable has values from a table and I fill it with a select

```
SqlDataAdapter sqlDa = new SqlDataAdapter("select concat(N1, ' ', N2, ' ',N3, ' ',N4, ' ',N5) FROM Cols2", sqlCon);
```

Comment: You are comparing the two DataRow objects, rather than the *values* in the two DataRow objects.

Comment: `row1 == row2` is checking if `row1` and `row2` refer to the same object. But I suspect you want to be checking if the values contained in the two `DataRow` instances are the same: you'll need to check  the columns yourself.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/comparing-datarows-linq-to-dataset

Comment: And more exactly the _"Find the intersection of the two tables"_ part  `var contacts = contacts1.AsEnumerable().Intersect(contacts2.AsEnumerable(),
                                                    DataRowComparer.Default);`

Comment: @xdtTransform I have already try this but it doesnt work...probably because my data are not in the same order...thank you

Comment: if (row1["Id"] == row2["Id"] &&row1["name"]==row2["name"] ) // and so on 
  {
   isRecordExist = true;
  }

Comment: @Mohammad Alghanem...I try it still the same result..I dont have an id to compare just one column..thank you

Comment: Please split a variables and see the values using debug , then you will know why condition is not firing, maybe you need to call .ToLower or .Trim() if you are comparing strings

Comment: @Mohammad Alghanem. Well lets say that in my 1st datatable I have a row with 1,2,3,4,5 and in my second 2,3,1,4,5 I want to remove this row from my third datatable...

Comment: You need to create compare method to cover your requirement nothing ready can help you in C#.
you need to create extension method to your for data row class , this extension method will compare the values and return true or false.

If your data row always numbers you can store it in array and then things will be easier by sorting (Arrays.Sort method)

Comment: `row1 == row2` is comparing `DataRow`s **by reference**, hence will always be `false`. You need to compare them by the row content (values) instead, for instance `DataRowComparer.Default.Equals(row1, row2)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a custom [MCVE]. Table 1 and Table2 have both an unique and duplicate row.

```
DataTable dataFromSourceA = new DataTable();    
DataTable dataFromSrouceB = new DataTable();

dataFromSourceA.Columns.Add("DataFromSourceA", typeof(string));
dataFromSrouceB.Columns.Add("DataFromSrouceB", typeof(string));

dataFromSourceA.Rows.Add("1,2,3,4,5"); // Dupe                
dataFromSourceA.Rows.Add("2,2");
dataFromSourceA.Rows.Add("4,5,6,7,8");

dataFromSourceB.Rows.Add("1,2,3,4,5"); // Dupe
dataFromSourceB.Rows.Add("2,2,2");
dataFromSourceB.Rows.Add("42");
```

You can simply use LinQ to query those Datable after using a `.AsEnumerable()`.
The row from T1 where Any row from T2 matches.

```
// List of Duplicate
var dupes =
   dataTable1
       .AsEnumerable()
       .Where(r1 =>
            dataTable2
               .AsEnumerable()
               .Any(r2 =>
                   {
                       var c1 = r1.Field<string>(0);
                       var c2 = r2.Field<string>(0);

                       var splitC1 = c1.Split(',').Select(x => x.Trim()).ToList();
                       var splitC2 = c2.Split(',').Select(x => x.Trim()).ToList();

                       return true
                              && (splitC1.Count() == splitC2.Count())
                              && !splitC1.Except(splitC2).Any();
                   }
                )
        );
```

Comment: thank you for your reply...it gives me 0 as a result. Unfontunately I have only one column,  no Id to compare..

Comment: Sorry you are right In one dtbl my column has values as 1,2,3,4,5 other row might be 2, 3 4, 5, 6 and in second I have 2,4,5,3,1 I need to comapre them and find dupicates...

Comment: `dataTable1`  and `dataTable2` doesnt have the same order. It doesnt matter as I access column by there name. But the code will be the same if we had to access them with index.

Comment: Sorry maybe for not being enough clear...Data as 1,2,3,4,5 they are in one row...

Comment: for exemple `Field<string>(3)` will give the  4th column

Comment: // 1, 2, 3, 4,5 => `table1.Select(x => new { x.Id, x.Price, x.Genre, x.Director, x.Label })`; // 2, 3, 1, 4, 5 = > `table2.Select(x => new { x.Price, x.Genre, x.Id, x.Director, x.Label })`. In my exemple they don't have the same column order. I Reordered them with a `Select`

Comment: You only have one column?

Comment: Yes I have only one

Comment: Why is this not in your question? Why dont you provide an code to reproduce your issue? If you have only one column giving an exemple of data from those two table is just copypasting one field… Edit your question. Make clear if 1,2,3 are int or text. make it clear if there is space, what is the separator. decimal value.

Comment: My god it feels like an X/Y. I will break the news you Don't have an isse with comparing row from Datatable. You have an issue because you use a datable instead of the right data type. DataTable is a structure used for display in a data grid view. You needed a 2d array

Comment: Edited for your data.

Comment: thank you...I tried with your data it always gives 0

Comment: Well it works .. https://rextester.com/GDF56377 . you should really try to read the [MCVE] guidlines. you fail to produce an exemple when you have only one column in the datable you failed to explain how a working code fail. From a legitimate question. We went from compare datatable to compare string "1,2,3,4,5" to "5,4,3,2,1" .. And thats an other subject.

Comment: Ok your example works now...I ll try  to modify to my needs

Comment: Sorry for coming back...but I need to delete duplicates no to print them out. I searched but I couldn't find a solution to merge with your example. Any idea? thank you again.

Comment: @touinta, Man you have an issue. What the difference "The duplicate" and "Not the duplicate"? Thats the answer. Read the last block of code line by line trying to understand what it does.

Comment: Well maybe I have get confused but I need to compare the one with another and get the unique values... those which exist only in first. No to print the duplicates...sorry for the misunderstanding ....I also read this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.except?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: Adding a `!` somewhere will solve your issue. As `!`, is a not in C#. The difference "The duplicate" and "Not the duplicate" was the Not.

Comment: The part in the `Any` code block is the definition of a duplicate on your weird formated information. So the whole block can be read as: In DT1, the element that are in DT2 with this definition for duplicate. So the `!` must be some**where**. I can't give more clue.

Comment: ok I put a ! in the `var rows = cols1.AsEnumerable().Where(r1 =>!cols2.AsEnumerable().Any(r2 =>` ....It works great!!! thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of the Except and Union function, using the default DataRowComparer:

```
    // create the 2 datatables - must have the same schema
    DataTable  dataTable1 = new DataTable();
    dataTable1.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Id"));
    dataTable1.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("FirstName"));
    dataTable1.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("LastName"));

    DataTable  dataTable2 = dataTable1.Clone(); 

    dataTable1.Rows.Add(new object[] {1, "John", "Doe"}); 
    dataTable1.Rows.Add(new object[] {2, "Peter", "Rabbit"});

    dataTable2.Rows.Add(new object[] {1, "John", "Doe"});
    dataTable2.Rows.Add(new object[] {2, "Peter", "Smith"});

    DataTable resultsTable = dataTable1.Clone();  // table to keep results

    // this will copy all distinct rows into the resultsTable 
    dataTable1.AsEnumerable()
            .Union(dataTable2.AsEnumerable().Except(dataTable1.AsEnumerable(), DataRowComparer.Default))   // all rows in table2 that do not exists in table1
        .ToList()   
        .ForEach(r => resultsTable.ImportRow(r));  // import the distinct rows into the resultsTable.

    DataTable resultsTable2 = dataTable1.Clone();
    // this will copy only the rows that DO NOT exist in both tables into the resultsTable2 (effectively deletes duplicate rows from both tables)
    dataTable1.AsEnumerable().Except(dataTable2.AsEnumerable(), DataRowComparer.Default)
            .Union(dataTable2.AsEnumerable().Except(dataTable1.AsEnumerable(), DataRowComparer.Default))   // all rows in table2 that do not exists in table1
        .ToList()   
        .ForEach(r => resultsTable2.ImportRow(r));  // import the distinct rows into the resultsTable.
```

Comment: @touinta - I might not have understood you correctly.  My previous answer only extracted rows that did not have an counterpart in the other table - only the rows that existed in only 1 of the 2 tables.  I have updated my answer to also extract the complete list of distinct rows.